# IS a command-line (Console) is important to learn for ASP.NET developer?

Tags: asp.net, command-line

I saw many RoR developers use command line to interact with interfaces and to deploy their web applications. Is that necessary step to earn for asp.net developer?

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET development, by and large, encourages the usage of Visual Studio for most tasks that would be performed from the command line in other environments. Is is possible to set up builds that do not use the IDE (at one point, I set up an ASP.NET project that used nant to build with aspnet_compiler), but it will be generally slower going and something of an uphill fight.

So, to answer your question, I would say that it is not *necessary* to learn it. However, the command line is one of the most direct interactions you can have with a computer. As a result, I tend to find its use advantageous in whatever line of software development I find myself. Therefore, I would recommend learning it and being comfortable with it.

Comment: Was just answering the question along these lines, but you put it more eloquently. +1.

Comment: Where can  I learn it?

Comment: @user4062 There are many ways to go about it. The most important step is to attempt to automate repetitive tasks (this will almost always lead you to the command line). Beyond that, if you are working on Windows, I would suggest looking into books on PowerShell. Cygwin/Unix style shell scripting is another gateway.

Answer (score 0):

While one can develop in ASP.Net and not use the command line, there are various tools where learning how to use the command line may be important such as using nAnt, nUnit, and writing scripts that may automate tasks outside of using Visual Studio. It isn't necessary but can be quite useful, particularly if the developer ever plans on managing Linux/Unix environments as part of their skill set.